# SQL error: Table name specified more than once

Tags: sql, database, netezza

I am getting the error `Table name specified more than once` after executing this code:

```
UPDATE Ref_zak_tab
SET uexdate = dbo.Data_inf.date
FROM dbo.Ref_zak_tab CROSS JOIN dbo.Data_inf
```

What can I do with this?

After trying alias I get this:

```
UPDATE Ref_zak_tab rzt
SET uexdate = dbo.Data_inf.date
FROM dbo.Ref_zak_tab CROSS JOIN dbo.Data_inf
```

`Update cancelled: attempt to update a target row with values from multiple join rows`

Comment: Give SQL version, table definitions and data! Although it looks like you are trying to assign multiple values to one row's column (impossible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to do what standard SQL would spell out as

`SET uexdate =
  (SELECT date 
     FROM dbo.Data_inf
    WHERE (condition here to determine single row in Data_inf) )`

?

If so, then just write it like that.

Answer (score 0):

For each row in the `Ref_zak_tab` table `CROSS JOIN` with the `Data_inf` table returns multiple rows and perhaps therefore `UPDATE` operator can not be successfully executed.

Try to use `INNER JOIN` instead.

```
UPDATE rzt
SET rzt.uexdate = dt.date
FROM dbo.Ref_zak_tab rzt
INNER JOIN dbo.Data_inf dt ON (*join condition here*)
```